# How to return DRF Forms data in the POST

Tags: django, forms, django-rest-framework

So I have a class based view views/users.py where the POST is supposed to send the data from the form to the serializer to validated it and if its alright create the user and return me the data, but for some reason it returns me a 404 bad request.

Here's the view:

```
class UserSignUpAPIView(APIView):
    """ User sign up API view. """
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'users/signup.html'

    def get(self, request):
        serializer = UserSignUpSerializer
        return Response({'serializer': serializer,})
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Handle HTTP POST request. """
        serializer = UserSignUpSerializer(data=request.data)
        
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            user = serializer.save()
            data = UserModelSerializer(user).data
            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The get function is working fine, it returns the template but when I submit the form, it returns a 404 BAD Request.

My serializer is the following serializers/users.py

```
class UserSignUpSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """ User sign up serializer. 

        Handle sign up data validation and user creation.
    """
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )

    username = serializers.CharField(
        min_length=4,
        max_length=20,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )

    password = serializers.CharField(
        min_length=8,
        max_length=64
    )

    password_confirmation = serializers.CharField(
        min_length=8,
        max_length=64
    )

    first_name = serializers.CharField(
        min_length=2,
        max_length=30
    )

    last_name = serializers.CharField(
        min_length=2,
        max_length=30
    )

    birth_date = serializers.DateField()

    def validate(self, data):
        """ Check that passwords match.
            Check that age of the user is over 16.
        """
        print('validate')
        # birth date validation
        dob = data['birth_date']
        print(dob)
        today = date.today()
        if (dob.year + 16, dob.month, dob.day) > (today.year, today.month, today.day):
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Must be at least 16 years old to register.')
        print('dob validated')
        # password validation
        passwd = data['password']
        passwd_conf = data['password_confirmation']

        if passwd != passwd_conf:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Passwords don't match.")
        password_validation.validate_password(passwd)

        print('password validated')
        return data

    def create(self, data):
        """ Handle user creation. """
        data.pop('password_confirmation')
        user = User.objects.create_user(**data)
        'user created'
        return user
```

and the template is the following

```
{% extends 'users/base.html' %}
{% load rest_framework %}

{% block head_content %}
    <title> Sign up </title>
{% endblock %}

{% block container %}
    <h3>Sign up here! </h3>
    <form action="{% url 'users:signup' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% render_form serializer %}

    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-5" type="submit"> Register </button>

    </form>
    <p class="mt-4"> Have an account already? <a href="{% url "users:login" %}">Log in here. </a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

I'm new with the DRF so I'm just wondering what has gone wrong, any ideas?

The console as I said only returns this:

```
Bad Request: /users/signup/
[22/Jan/2021 15:56:51] "POST /users/signup/ HTTP/1.1" 400 15
```

Answer (score 1):

I've edited the post function like this and it worked:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Handle HTTP POST request. """
        serializer = UserSignUpSerializer(data=request.data)

        if not serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            return Response({'serializer': serializer,})

        serializer.save()

        return redirect('users:login')
```

I was trying to simulate what's on the documentation for [DRF forms](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/)